# Simple Sieve of Eratosthenes in Python 3

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, sieve-of-eratosthenes

So yet another Sieve of Eratosthenes in Python 3.

The function returns a list of all primes smaller but not equal `max_n`.

The motivation is, as a practice, a simple implementation of the algorithm that is faithful, short, readable and transparent, while still getting a reasonable performance.

```
def primes(max_n):
    """Return a list of primes smaller than max_n."""

    sieve = [True] * max_n

    # p contains the largest prime yet found.
    p = 2

    # Only for p < sqrt(max_n) we check,
    # i.e. p ** 2 < max_n, to avoid float issues.
    while p ** 2 < max_n:

        # Cross-out all true multiples of p:
        for z in range(2 * p, max_n, p):
            sieve[z] = False

        # Find the next prime:
        for z in range(p + 1, max_n):
            if sieve[z]:
                p = z
                break

    # 0 and 1 are not returned:
    return [z for z in range(2, max_n) if sieve[z]]
```

IMHO it would be preferable to avoid `p ** 2 < max_n` and instead use `p < max_n ** 0.5`. Can we do this? It surprisingly *seems* to work as long as `max_n ** 0.5` fits into the float mantissa, even if `max_n` doesn’t.

The second `for`-loop doesn’t look very nice with the `break` but I don’t have any idea how to do it otherwise…

Do you have any suggestions?

Are there still any simplifications possible? Or non-hackish ways to increase performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The second for-loop doesn’t look very nice with the break ...

You can remove that for-loop if you test `p` for being prime in the while-loop:

```
while p ** 2 < max_n:
    if sieve[p]:
        # p is prime: cross-out all true multiples of p:
        for z in range(2 * p, max_n, p):
            sieve[z] = False
    p += 1
```

> Are there still any simplifications possible? Or non-hackish ways to increase performance?

Here are two simple changes which increase the performance:
First, since 2 is the only even prime, you can increment `p` by two after the first iteration:

```
    p = p + 2 if p > 2 else 3
```

Second, it suffices to “cross-out” the multiples of `p` starting at `p*p` (instead of `2*p`) because all lesser multiples have been handled before:

```
        for z in range(p * p, max_n, p):
            sieve[z] = False
```

Comment: `It suffices to “cross-out” the multiples of p starting at p*p` how could I not see this!!! ;-) . Now it’s 8 lines of actual code.